# How to write "javadoc" statements in Thrift IDL?

Tags: thrift

Thrift has a *html* generator:

(`thrift --help`)

```
html (HTML):
standalone:      Self-contained mode, includes all CSS in the HTML files.
                 Generates no style.css file, but HTML files will be larger.
```

If write a `struct` like this

```
/**
* This is description of struct MyStruct
**/
struct MyStruct {
    1: required i32 fieldOne = 2
}
```

running `thrift --gen html` creates an html page with part like this:

```
Struct MyStruct

|Key|Field   |Type|Description|Requiredness|Default value|
|---|--------|----|-----------|------------|-------------|
|1  |fieldOne|i32 |           |required    |2            |

This is description of struct MyStruct
```

But I don't found how to fill `description` field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question, this is hard to guess and not super well documented (yes I'm being generous). Here's the answer:

```
struct MyStruct {
     /** This is how you add a description to a struct field */
     1: required i32 fieldOne = 2
}
```

Comment: You mean, if we ignore the [test/DocTest.thrift](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/test/DocTest.thrift) file ;-)? Especially that one has a lot of documented (pun intended) details.